# How can I package my-helper.cmake scripts in a conan package, and make them available to other packages in the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH

Tags: conan

I have a lot of projects which all share the use of some helper `.cmake` scripts.

I would like to create a Conan package which has all the helper scripts in it, and include it in the other projects. I can build and package the helper scripts. They exist in the Conan `package` directory, but when I include the helper package in another project, Conan doesn't append the helper `package` directory to the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.

How can I automatically append the project directory path from a dependency to the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` and use the helper `*.cmake` scripts it provides?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - I packaged the cmake files I want to export.

```
class HelpersConan(ConanFile):

    exports_sources = ["cmake/**"]
```

Then added the package directory to `package_info` function.

```
def package_info(self):
    
    self.cpp_info.builddirs = ["package"]
```

At the top of my cmake file, I call the find package script for my packaged cmake files.

```
find_package(Helpers REQUIRED)
```

After doing this, I was able to include my cmake helpers.

```
include(helpers)
```